# xlPasteAll is changing a fixed criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA, I've created a new column and populating it with VLOOKUP to a range in another worksheet.

H2 is a code, and 'Start!A2' is the code, and 'Start!B2' is the corresponding column/value I want.

```
Range("G2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(H2,Start!A2:B9,2)"
Range("G2").Copy
Range("G2:G" & x).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
```

My problem is that the range part of my formula adjusts along with the criteria.

I want the range (Start!A2:B9) to remain static when I paste the formula.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use `Range("G2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(H2,Start!$A$2:$B$9,2)"` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$` in front of the row or column that should not change, and set all formulas at once:

```
Range("G2:G" & x).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(H2,Start!A$2:B$9,2)"
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I've struggled over this many times. 
Thanks!